# key by navigation property using annotation (entity framework)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I have a class as

```
 public class fooClass
{
     [Key]
    public virtual fooRefClass staff { get; set; }


    public Int64 fooProp1{ get; set; }

    public DateTime fooProp2{ get; set; }
}
```

when i do the migration it give me error as "no key defined" but i had added the key attonation already .My intention is to make the referenced entity "fooRefClass " as primary key as well as foreign key, i know there is a way by mentioning the attribute id of the referenced entity and writing the foreign-key annotate over there, but i want to deal with entity directly ,rather than id only, how can i attain this functionality ,please help me with the issue.

Comment: staff is a NAVIGATION PROPERTY! It won't even appear in the table! Of course you can't set it to a key, if it won't be in the database. Create a Foreign Key Property and use it.

Comment: I have a fooRefClass entity as different class and ef had created a table for the same and if i make key to some other attribute then ef creates fk of the same

Comment: that does not really make any sense... just add a FK property to fooRefClass and define it as key+FK?!

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be confusion, I decided to write an answer as well.

With the class you defined, EF would expect a table like

```
fooClass(bigint fooRefClass_Id, bigint fooProp1, datetime fooProp2);
```

... which is not valid, because this has no key column (the key annotation on your navigation property does nothing, because you see, it won't appear in the table... it will just tell EF there is a relationship to this table, and because you didn't provide a FK, it creates one to create this relationship). You also can't create this relationship yourself in your current model, because you don't even have a FK... how would you access a property you know nothing about, just that it will be created at some point (usually upon model creating with first accessing the database).
You have to tell EF you want the property, that will be created, to also be a key, not only a foreign key. You can do this by simply creating the property yourself and telling EF you want to use this, for example (I'm not too familiar with Data Annotations, I usually use Fluent API, so please excuse maybe occuring errors)

```
[Key, Foreign Key(fooRefClass)]
public Int64 StaffId {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thnks for ur response but as i mentioned in my question that i knw the above solution but i want to deal with entity only else the get and post request json signatures would be different